# How to copy a file between two Linux machines?

Tags: linux

I'm connecting from a Linux server (Machine 1) to another Linux server (Machine 2) using PuTTY.

Using WinSCP, I have copied a `zip` file from my hard disk in Windows to the Machine 1's home directory.

How can I copy this zip file from the Machine 1 to the Machine 2's build/test_builds directory?

Comment: you can use SCP but you don't know how to copy to a particular folder?

Comment: ftp, sftp are a couple of others

Answer (score 16):

```
scp sourcefile ssh://[user]@[hostname]/[destination path]
```

I think this should work with every linux box with ssh enabled, maybe you'll need to enable secure copy (scp)

A better way to write this can be:

```
scp source destination
```

source and destination can be:

- absolute or relative path to file (eg. `/tmp/foo.txt` or `./foo.txt`)
- ssh file path (in the form ssh://[user]@[machine]/[path]

You can also perform copies between machine1 and machine2, while being on machine3 (given that you've got access - eg. a logon to each machine) via:

```
scp ssh://user@machine1/path ssh://user@machine2/path
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ,please tell me whether  this hostname is refering Machiene 1 or Machiene 2 ??

Comment: hostname is target machine, if you're executing the command on Machine1 will copy Machine1's file to Machine2

Comment: Additionally, if you need to run a copy and not use the default port of 22 you can use the following syntax:

scp -P [portNum] [source file path] ssh://[user]@[hostname]/[destination folder path]

Answer (score 6):

As per man I have changed the scp command as follows and it has worked for me.

```
scp user@sourceservername:sourcefilepath user@destservername:destdirectory
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync -r --progress SRC DST
```

works also nice: retransfer, progress-bar

Answer (score 0):

To transfer between two linux boxes use scp like the above user suggested. His syntax is a little off for ssh though. With scp the format is

`scp [options] source destination`

Which is available in the man pages `man scp`

for you the syntax from machine 1 is

`scp /path/to/file.zip user@ip.of.machine.2:port/path/to/destination/dir/`

port default is **22**

Comment: scp /path/to/file user@ip.of.machine.2:/path/to/destination/dir/ works for me! no port requiered.

Comment: Defining the port using the syntax above did not work for me.  Instead, I added the -P switch just after scp and defined the port number that way.

scp -P portNum /path/to/file.zip user@ip.of.machine.2:/path/to/destination/dir/

Comment: Yeah, there is no port definition in mine. As you found out, to define the port you need the `-P` option (which is in the `man` page I mentioned).

Answer (score -2):

```
rsync -aPv --update /path/to/desire/file /path/to/destination/same_name_as_file
```

`-a` — archive mode, a combination of several other rsync options that is useful for backing up
`-P` — same as `--partial --progress`
`-v` — `--verbose`

Comment: There is [another answer](http://superuser.com/a/345699/461558) which suggests `rsync` - can you elaborate and explain more?